# Say if there is an element in $\Bbb Z_{900}$ with 30 as additive and multiplicative order

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, ring-theory

I have a ring $\Bbb Z_{900}$ and I need to check if there is an element which has multiplicative and additive order 30.
I think that is sufficient to check if the following system has at least one solution:

$$\begin{cases} 
\begin{aligned}
     30x&\equiv0\ (\text{mod}\ 900) \\
  x^{30}&\equiv1\ (\text{mod}\ 900)  
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}$$

If my attempt is correct, how can I solve the system? The first congruence is easy to solve. How can I solve the second? Is there a method to reduce the power?

Comment: Hi Jack. What numbers can satisfy the first equation in your system? --- Consider that first, then see if there is any way any of them can satisfy the second. It might be useful to use that 900=30*30

Comment: the first equation is true for $x=900t, t \in Z$

Comment: Is it true for 30? Is $30 = 900t$ for some $t\in \mathbb{Z}$? You might want to put some more thought into the numbers that satisfy equation 1.

Comment: could you be more detailed? I don't think I understand what you mean.

Comment: What $x\in[1,899]\cap \mathbb Z$ satisfy the equation? That 900 does is trivial, but there are more values, and they have a particular form if you consider their prime decomposition. Once you have that, you should be able to see if there is any way any of those can satisfy the second equation.

Comment: Any element satisfying the second equality will be invertible. But then it will have order what additively?

Comment: @kholli basically they are multiple of 900 and they must divide each prime factor of 900...

Comment: No, they don't need to be multiples of $900$, for example for $x=60$, we have $30x = 1800 = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$30x \equiv 0 \, \,  (\text{mod } 900) \Rightarrow 30x = 900z \ni z \in \mathbb{N} \Rightarrow x = 30z$. Now then $(30z)^3 = 30^3z^3 = 0 \, \,  (\text{mod } 900)$. So there isn't any solution to that system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you please be more detailed in the steps? For example, how do I get this step $30x \equiv 0 \, \,  (\text{mod } 900) \Rightarrow 30x = 900z \ni z \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: $900/30x$ for $30x = 0$ mod 900. $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ but since we are talking about elements in $Z_{900}$, we can only consider positive integers and including 0.

Comment: Forgive me, but I still don't understand.I don't understand how you can write $30=900$ without first "removing" 30... I've never seen this way of resolving a linear congruence